# How to get remote server hostname as variable and use it?

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, csv, ssh

How to get remote server hostname and use it as filename variable? With this code I'm only getting local machine's hostname...

This script has array of servers, connects to all of them and runs commands to unzip file, sorts CSV file by date descending, leaves first 40 lines and uploads to server.

In arrays there are IPs of servers, not hostnames.

```
file=$(hostname)$(date +%Y_%m_%d)

for server in "${servers[@]}"

do

ssh -t $user@$server << EOF

    unzip -o "$location1"/1.zip -d "$localdir"/
    cp -v "$localdir"/1.csv "$localdir"/jobs_optimized.csv
    head -1 "$localdir"/jobs_optimized.csv > "$localdir"/"$file".csv |\
    tail -n+2 "$localdir"/jobs_optimized.csv |\
    sort -rn -t, -k5.7,5.10 -k5.4,5.5 -k 5.1,5.2 >> "$localdir"/"$file".csv
    head -40 "$localdir"/"$file".csv > "$remotedir"/"$file".csv
    ls "$remotedir"
EOF

scp $user@$server:$remotedir/"$failas".csv /tmp/


done
```

Comment: You __have__ the remote server hostname in a variable already.  How else would you `ssh` to it otherwise.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because there is no question here.

Comment: In array there's only IPs of servers. I need to get hostnames.

Comment: Option 1: Do `hostname` on the remote server.  Option 2: Use `dig` or `nslookup` to resolve the hostname.

Comment: I tried something like this, but cannot make my "$file".csv to represent as hostname_date.csv

Answer (score 0):

You can create the filename at the remote host:

```
    # ....
    head -40 "$localdir"/"$file".csv > "$remotedir"/"$file_$(hostname)".csv
    ls "$remotedir"
EOF

scp $user@$server:$remotedir/"$failas*".csv /tmp/
```

Comment: Thanks, but does not help either. With `"$(hostname)_$(date +%Y_%m_%d)".csv` I get local machine hostnames.

Comment: @Edgaras, oh yes. You can create the here-document as a script and copy/execute it on the remote host.